# Disabling/uninstall Joomla only on the front-end

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla site and smoothly I started to move out all my sections from Joomla. I've finished all the front-end switch, but I still depend from Joomla to insert the articles and send the newsletter (back-end).

That's why I only want to disable or un-install Joomla only on the front-end side and leave running the back-end only, Or at least remove all the files/folders that are on the front-end, so they are not public accesible.

Answer (score 1):

One option is you could take your site offline by going to the backend then Site > Global Configuration > Site

You can set a custom message for public visitors but they won't be able to access your site, everything will be normal on the back end though.

More info at https://docs.joomla.org/Taking_the_website_temporarily_offline

Good luck!